# How to shift the site content to the upper most of the page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, layouts

I need to modify my current SharePoint layout as follow:-

1. To display the site collection name inside the upper blue horizontal bar , as shown in the below picture.
2. To remove the free space on the top of the site collection content, and then shift the quick lunch links and the site collection contents to occupy this empty space , as shown in the below picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

go into sharepoint designer, open up the site, navigate to masterpages, look in design view and move around the controls to your liking! save the changed and refresh page